# TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a function when using web3 on meteor server side

Tags: meteor, server-side, ethereum, web3js

I get the error `TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a function` when I try to interact with a contract on the server side of my meteor application.

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))

var cocontract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);
var name = (cocontract.name())
```

The error is raised with the 3rd line. If I run the same code on the client side I don't get a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Instead `ethereum:web3` Meteor package I have used `web3@0.20.1` NPM package, and it works ok (Meteor version 1.5.1).
So, if you using `ethereum:web3` you probably need to run:

```
meteor remove ethereum:web3
meteor npm install web3@0.20.1 --save
```

and replace

```
import { Web3 } from 'meteor/ethereum:web3';
```

with

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used web3, but I suspect it's taking advantage of the `XMLHttpRequest`, which is only present in browsers. Try getting an analogue for that on the server. I'd start with this one:
[xmlhttprequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest)

Comment: I believe web3 comes with the  xmlhttprequest node module